# Меню с SVG фильтрами (Goo effect)

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация

Есть меню, которое реализовано на `HTML`/`CSS`. Мне пришла идея сделать его совместно с `SVG`фильтрами, а конкретно с эффектом "вязкости" (**Goo**) для каждого элемента меню.

**1.** Пример с **Goo**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.** Меню, которое нужно сделать с таким эффектом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Как правильно применить фильтры для этого меню?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Фильтры `SVG` - это довольно огромная тема.
Одни из самых широко применяемых - `<feGaussianBlur/>`, который присутствует также в `CSS` ( `filter: blur(N)` ), `<feColorMatrix/>`,
`<feBlend>`,
`<feComposite/>`,
`<feImage/>`,
`<feMerge/>` и так далее.

В данном случае мы будем применять `<feGaussianBlur/>`, `<feColorMatrix/>` и `<feComposite/>`.

**Первый шаг:**

- Возьмём для начала "каркас":

```js
$(".goo-button").on("click", function() {
  $(".goo-button").toggleClass("active");
  $(".goo-button span").toggleClass("active");
  $(".circle").toggleClass("goo-active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}

.goo-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0066ff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: ease-out 200ms;
}

.goo-button.active {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.goo-menu span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.goo-menu span:first-child {
  top: 26px;
  left: 15px;
}

.goo-menu span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 36px;
  left: 15px;
}

.goo-menu span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 46px;
  left: 15px;
}

.goo-menu span.active:first-child {
  top: 36px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.goo-menu span.active:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.goo-menu span.active:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: #0066ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: ease-out 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c1.goo-active {
  top: 105px;
  left: 20px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.c2.goo-active {
  top: 20px;
  left: 105px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.c3.goo-active {
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="goo-menu">
    <div class="goo-button">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle c1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></div>
    <div class="circle c2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></div>
    <div class="circle c3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Второй шаг:**

- Теперь нам нужно использовать сами фильтры, но перво-наперво немного
  теории.

  `SVG` фильтры модифицируют графические объекты. Каждый элемент
  фильтра содержит в себе набор примитивов фильтров, которые выполняют
  определённую графическую операцию. Мы можем использовать результат
  операции как входной сигнал для другого фильтра, создавая
  ограниченный охват возможностей для эффектов.
- Самый обычный пример с использованием фильтра `<feGaussianBlur/>`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="300" height="250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blurEffect">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5 3" />
      <!--5 - горизонтальное, 3 - вертикальное размытие -->
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="250" height="150" fill="blue" filter="url(#blurEffect)" />  
</svg>
```

Фильтры для `HTML`-элементов подключаются таким образом:

```
.elem{
  -webkit-filter: url("#filter");
  filter: url("#filter");
}
```

**Третий шаг:**

- После того, как мы разобрались, можно приступать к созданию эффекта
  "вязкости (или липкости).

  В последнем фрагменте кода мы использовали 3 операции:

  1. `<feGaussianBlur/>` для создания размытия
  2. `<feColorMatrix/>` для увеличения контрастности альфа-канала
  3. `<feComposite/>` для видимости содержимого

```js
$(".goo-button").on("click", function() {
  $(".goo-button").toggleClass("active");
  $(".goo-button span").toggleClass("active");
  $(".circle").toggleClass("goo-active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}


/*Подключаем наши фильтры*/

.goo-menu {
  -webkit-filter: url(#gooEffect");
  filter: url("#gooEffect");
}

.goo-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0066ff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.goo-button.active {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.goo-menu span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 4px;
  transition: all 400ms;
}

.goo-menu span:first-child {
  top: 26px;
  left: 15px;
}

.goo-menu span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 36px;
  left: 15px;
}

.goo-menu span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 46px;
  left: 15px;
}

.goo-menu span.active:first-child {
  top: 36px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.goo-menu span.active:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.goo-menu span.active:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: #0066ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: ease-out 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c1.goo-active {
  top: 105px;
  left: 20px;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.c2.goo-active {
  top: 20px;
  left: 105px;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.c3.goo-active {
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="goo-menu">
    <div class="goo-button">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle c1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></div>
    <div class="circle c2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></div>
    <div class="circle c3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="gooEffect">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" result="mix"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**P.S.** Воздерживайтесь от применения этих фильтров на больших площадях, так как они достаточно ресурсоёмкие.